# With JSON.Net if serializing Entity Framework object, disable trips to the database

Tags: c#, .net, json, entity-framework, json.net

With JSON.Net I wish to configure it so that if serializing an Entity Framework object, it will do so entirely from what's already fetched and in .NET memory, essentially, disable additional trips to the database.

I found an equivalent question for nHibernate, but I don't know how to go about it for EF.

Comment: Are you referring this relating to serializing navigation properties?

Answer (score 1):

You can disable lazy loading by setting the context configuration and you can also disable creating proxies

```
// Disable lazy loading
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
// Disable proxies
context.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

But as others already pointed out this is bad design and you should reconsider sending EF objects at all and rather create DTOs with LinQ.

**Edit:** In the comments of another answer it was pointed out by @raderick, that this may have side effects. I therefore recommend turning it back on if your context is still used after serializing the objects. Keep in mind that objects created with `ProxyCreationEnabled = false` don't magically convert to proxies when you switch it back on.

```
// Reactivate lazy loading
context.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to manaully fetch whole object using `.Include()` for all navigational properties being serialized, so that they were loaded from DB before serialization happens. Otherwise each property that allows lazy loading will be fetched from data base with a separate query - for single property it's 1 query, for collection it's 1 query per collection item, and then the process is repeated for each lazy loaded entity until whole graph is serialized.

Also, it's overall a very bad practice to serialize Entity Framework proxies or domain entities, which might likely lead to a bunch of different issues - N+1, not fetched data, too many properties serialized, an additional property needed to add to serialized object, etc. etc.. I suggest switching to DTOs that you serialize and return only them, and map your Entity Framework entities to those DTOs.

Comment: Even though you are right this does not answer his question but rather provide a workaround.

Comment: @Toxantron his question was about trips to database - the answer is to use Include() to fetch lazily loaded properties, I believe.

Comment: His questions states he wants to only serialize what was allready fetched. So disabling lazy loading would be the way to go IMO.

Comment: @Toxantron disabling lazy loading is often a solution-wide action, that might lead to big impact on whole application breaking lots of stuff, that requires a lot of careful testing or big number of unit-tests. I prefer lazy loading disabled by default, but not really sure that this option won't have bad side effects for OP

Comment: Who would use the same context instance trough an entire application? Aren't you supposed to use it like a transaction? Open context, get your shit down, close context.

Comment: @Toxantron there are patterns like session-per-request in web projects, that keep one DbContext open from beginning of request straight to the end. Changing context options in this case might have very weird side effects on whole application.

Comment: Agreed. He can however simply reactivate it after execution.